# php table text align center

Tags: php, html

I want to align text in center under table but i dnt know how to do this
Here is my code

```
 echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] ." ". $row['Lastname'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Marks'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['percent'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
```

Kindly help me how to do this.
i tried this but not working

```
 echo '<td tyle="text-align:center;">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you did typo there.replace `tyle` with `style`

```
  echo '<td style="text-align:center;">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

or you can also try

```
  echo '<td align="center">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS

```
.Classname td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

In Inline

```
echo '<td style="text-align:center;">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Or

```
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, include this code to see the table borders `<table border="1">`

Next, include this *before* your `</header>` tag if you got everything in an HTML Doctype:

```
<style type="text/css">
table td {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

And your done.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead:

```
.tableClass td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Inline styles are annoying to try and maintain, especially if they're output using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `align` attribute for `td` :

```
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use css or inside code write as:

```
echo '<td style='.'"'.'text-align:center'.';">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because there is a typing error - missing **s** in style

```
 echo '<td tyle="text-align:center;">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

should be

```
 echo '<td style="text-align:center;">' . $row['enroll'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score -1):

**php table text align center**

echo " < td align='center'>" . $row['enroll'] . "< /td>";

Comment: What explanation does this add that earlier answers did not?